# PySpark Timeseries indicator event column, extract data before and after event occurs

Tags: pyspark

I am working with a spark dataframe containing a timeseries data and one of the columns is an indicator for an event. looking something like the dummy table below.

| id | time | timeseries_data | event_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:00 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:01 | 2 | 0 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:02 | 3 | 0 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:03 | 4 | 1 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:04 | 5 | 0 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:05 | 6 | 0 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:00 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:01 | 2 | 0 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:02 | 3 | 1 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:03 | 4 | 0 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:04 | 5 | 0 |
| b | 2022-08-12 08:05 | 6 | 0 |

I now want to select samples before and after (including the sample where the event occurs). to start off one sample before and after, but also by time so everything within 4 minutes of the event for each id.

I've tried to use the window function but I don't know how to sort it out.
The result for id a is shown below. the event occurs 2022-08-12 08:03 at sample 4 and I now want to extract the following to a new dataframe.

| id | time | timeseries_data | event_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:02 | 3 | 0 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:03 | 4 | 1 |
| a | 2022-08-12 08:04 | 5 | 0 |

Edit:
I thought it would be a very simple solution to this problem, and I am just new to PySpark that's why I don't really get it to work.

What I've tried is to use a window function per id.

```
windowPartition = Window.partitionBy([F.col("id")]).orderBy("time").rangeBetween(-1, 1)
test_df = df_dummy.where(F.col('event_indicator') == 1).over(windowPartition)
```

however, the error is that df_dummy does not have object 'over'. So I need to figure out a way to apply this window to the entire dataframe and not just a function.
The lag/lead from my understanding is only to take the lagged/lead value and I want a consecutive dataframe of the time around the event_indicator.
The timestamp is only dummy data, for me currently it does not matter if the window over is per minute or per second so I've changed the question to per minute.

Currently the goal is to get an understanding how I can extract a subset of the entire timeseries dataframe. This to see how the data changes when something happens. An example could be a normal car driving, one tyre explodes and we want to see what happened with the pressure the x timeseries samples before and after the explosion. And the next step might not be to use samples but instead what happened with the data the previous minute and the following minute of data.

Comment: `where event = 1 or lag(event) = 1 or lead(event) = 1` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you please share your attempt?

Comment: I've shared the 2 lines of code I've tried. I have not used lag(event) = 1 as my understanding of lag is that it moves the lagged row to the new place. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Emil

Solution :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window 
data = [("a","2022-08-12 08:00","1","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:01","2","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:02","3","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:03","4","1"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:04","5","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:05","6","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:10","7","0"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:12","8","1"),
("a","2022-08-12 08:14","9","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:00","1","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:01","2","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:02","3","1"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:03","4","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:04","5","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:05","6","0"),
("b","2022-08-12 08:10","7","0"), # thesearemy testcase,shouldn't in output
("b","2022-08-12 08:12","8","1"), # theseare my testcase,shouldn't in output
 ("b","2022-08-12 08:17","9","0")] # thesearemy testcase,shouldn't in output
schema=["id","time","timeseries_data","event_indicator"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
df= df.withColumn("time",F.col("time").cast("timestamp"))\
.withColumn("event_indicator",F.col("event_indicator").cast("int"))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy(["id"]).orderBy("time")
window_spec_groups_all = Window.partitionBy(["id","continous_groups"])
flag_cond_ = ((F.lag(F.col("event_indicator")).over(window_spec)==1) | (F.col("event_indicator")==1)
               |(F.lead(F.col("event_indicator")).over(window_spec)==1))
four_minutes_cond_ = (F.unix_timestamp(F.last(F.col("time")).over(window_spec_groups_all))-F.unix_timestamp(F.first(F.col("time")).over(window_spec_groups_all)))
df_flt= df.withColumn("flag",F.when(flag_cond_,F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False)))\
.withColumn("org_rnk",F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
.filter(F.col("flag"))\
.withColumn("flt_rnk",F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
.withColumn("continous_groups",(F.col("org_rnk")-F.col("flt_rnk")).cast("int"))\
.withColumn("four_minutes_cond_",four_minutes_cond_)\
.filter(F.col("four_minutes_cond_") <=240)\
.select(schema)
df_flt.show(20,0)
```

output:-

```
+---+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|id |time               |timeseries_data|event_indicator|
+---+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|a  |2022-08-12 08:02:00|3              |0              |
|a  |2022-08-12 08:03:00|4              |1              |
|a  |2022-08-12 08:04:00|5              |0              |
|a  |2022-08-12 08:10:00|7              |0              |
|a  |2022-08-12 08:12:00|8              |1              |
|a  |2022-08-12 08:14:00|9              |0              |
|b  |2022-08-12 08:01:00|2              |0              |
|b  |2022-08-12 08:02:00|3              |1              |
|b  |2022-08-12 08:03:00|4              |0              |
+---+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: within 4 seconds means  event=1 , the records before and after should be within 4 seconds taking the  time of event=1 as ref or my understanding is wrong .

Comment: For me the data is a dummy data and I want to have an understanding how to enclose before/after an event in time and put it in a new dataframe. It currently does not matter if that is on minute or second level.
So first question is how to find the events and create a new dataframe with samples before/after the event trigger.  I know where the event is because of the column 'event_indicator' == 1 and now I want to extract samples in range [-x, x] from each event. 
Second part is to extract samples within [-time,time] from the event_indicator to a new df.

Comment: okay . Let me post the solution . do let me know if you have any questions around this.